# Unable to get python to get variable into string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please read and try to help before saying it's a repeat question - I know it is, however, I am unable to get it working even finding other solutions.

I am having issues getting python 2.7 to let me put a variable into a string. This string I am planning to use with the subprocess module if that makes a difference.

I have tried `%(var_name)`, `f'string here'`, also, `from string import Template`

Below is my code as it stands along with the error message I am getting when I am trying to run my script.

Current code:

```
def status(node):
    print node
    command= "echo 'Node is: %(node)'"
    print command
    args = shlex.split(command)
    print args
    result = subprocess.Popen(args)
    print result
```

Current output/error

```
master
echo 'Node is: %(node)'
['echo', 'Node is: %(node)']
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f565cb12ad0>
slave
echo 'Node is: %(node)'
['echo', 'Node is: %(node)']
Node is: %(node)
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f565cb12a10>
Node is: %(node)
```

What am I missing that is preventing me from creating a string based on the input to the function. I want to be able to run the string as a command but that's another issue.

Comment: https://pyformat.info/ (the only thing missing there is: `f"Node is: {node}"`).

Comment: What output do you expect to get?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I tried that, see my OP as to what I have tried.

Comment: @Sayse I expect it to give me first `master` then `slave` in my output (this function is ran over an array via foreach)

Comment: oh. indeed: f-strings will not work in python 2.7. `"Node is: {}".format(node)` will. please read the link i posted. *everything* you need is there. you could use `'Node is %(node)s' % {'node': node}`.

Comment: Josh the "%" old notation does not accept variable names, you have to provide the params you want to pass to the format string: `"echo 'Node is: %s'" % node`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change

```
command = "echo 'Node is: %(node)'"
```

to

```
command = "echo 'Node is: %(node)s'" % {'node': node}
```

You need to add the format specifier `s` to your `%` sign and then also pass the variable `node` into the string. Read about [named placeholders for string formatting](https://pyformat.info/#named_placeholders).

---

Or you can also use `'{}'.format()` like this:

```
command = "echo 'Node is: {}'".format(node)
```

Comment: that alone will not work. you still need the `%` operator after the format string: `echo 'Node is: %s' % node`.

Comment: How would adding the `s` make a difference? would that not just get put into my string? If so that won't work because this is not going to be a echo string when I am done but this is more getting something working that I can copy into what I actually need.

Comment: @JoshKirby read [this part](https://pyformat.info/#named_placeholders) about `%s` with named placeholders

Comment: even if you have named placeholders you need the `%` operator. these are not f-strings! `'Node is %(node)s' % {'node': node}` would work.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I was only pointed out the minimal part that needed changing, not the whole line; I'll edit it for you